# bootstrap dropdown partially working in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table filled with server names.  When I click on the link it goes to a page with various information about said server.  I'm using SSO to determine is a user has the ability to change some of the fields via a dropbox box with selectable items.  This is all working great....as a page

However, I want to convert that page into a modal.  I have the modal working, it pulls all the information...however, the dropdown box only works every other time.  No exaggeration, every other time.  I click a server, the modal comes up and no values in the dropdown.  I can inspect it with firebug and see it has values in the list for the dropdown but nothing happens.  I close the modal, click on a link (the same or different) and the dropdown works just fine

This is my html

```
<td><a href="{{ url_for('vm', vm=vm.GuestName) }}" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#vmModal" data-toggle="modal"> {{ vm.GuestName }}</a></td>
```

Here is my modal

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="vmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3 id="myModalLabel">Virtual Machine Info</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="height: 600px; right: 12px">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Here is my dropdown

```
{% if access %}
        <div class="dropdown">
            <li>
                <strong>Service:</strong>
                <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> {{ item.Service }} <b
                        class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    {% for service in service_data %}
                        <li><a tabindex="-1"
                               href="/api?name={{ item.GuestName }}&service={{ service.name }}"> {{ service.name }}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>
```

Comment: My initial thought is that the transition/animation is conflicting with the bootstrap dropdown js plugin. Try removing the animation `fade in` classes from the modal and see if that fixes it. If that's the case then we can sort it out relatively easily.

Comment: Nope, still the same.  Every other time it works fine

However, I like it better without the fade...going to keep that part!

Comment: So if you see the values in the list as you said, I assume you are seeing all the various `<li>` you expect, then the problem has got to be with the bootstrap dropdown js. I assume you are getting no errors in the console? If you call `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` after the page has loaded or in the `shown` method of the modal does it show it every time like you'd expect? (That way we can at least try to isolate whether its something with the click events or the dropdown action itself that might be having the problem.

Comment: Here is what i'm seeing when I use firebug....

under the <div class="dropdown"> i see the <li>.  When its working the <li> becomes <li class="open"> but every other time it doesn't ever add class="open"

I manually add class="open" and the list is populated, but that means the list starts open.  when I close the list, it wont open again

Comment: Are you able to open the dropdown via javascript without relying on mouse click using `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()`?

Comment: Not gonna like and pretend I know about everything.  This is all relatively new to me.  I've only ever used the dropdown by including the bootstrap.min.js

Where do i go about writing the javascript to make this work

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your problem, but it should work without issue. Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/digthedoug/j5bfr/ and see if it fixes your problem. If so just use it for your template, there must have been some error within some code you have you haven't posted yet. If it doesn't fix your error or work for you reply back with what doesn't work and what browser you're using etc.

Comment: Nope, still the same issue.  Still i only get the drop down to work every other time. 

This is a flask application...and i'm setting up templates.  I use {% extends %} to pull in from my base template. Could that be causing things to be a little wonky?

Comment: Just to be clear when you visit that jsfiddle link, it only works for you ever other time there as well? The reason I ask is that I'm trying to isolate your actual issue. Without seeing all your code and its actual implementation its not clear to me yet what could be causing the issue.

Comment: Sorry, no, the fiddle works every time...when I change my code to use the fiddle it doesn't change anything for MY modal/dropdown issues

Answer (score 4):

I just solved a very similar problem where my modal-dialog caused the drop-down menu to work only every other time I opened the modal-dialog. The drop-down menu would work initially. but if I opened and closed the modal, it would stop working. Then if I opened the modal and closed it again, the drop-down menu would work again. The problem was simply that my target url that contained the modal-content was referencing the bootstrap.js file when it was already referenced in the parent page. Therefore, all I had to do is remove the following from the modal-content page:

```
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Edit: Actually, when I removed it from the modal-content page, other elements stopped working so I added it back. Instead, I added it in their twice, once at the top of the page and again at the bottom of the page before the  tag. Now it works every time. I don't get it. Does anyone else know why this is happening?

Fabrice G, I tried what you recommended but I couldn't get it to work that way. I must have a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have the same issue;
After long analyse i find the solution :
Adding "style="display:none;" on div modal. I don't know why but when you load the page the modal is hidden, but if you inspect with firebug the modal recover the dropdown.
After shown the modal and hidden it; the js add "style="display:none;" and dropdown works.